# Create a json in SQL server with one column as key and another as value

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL server I am trying to get two column values in the same row as a dictionary
Example
Table having columns Key,Value
So the dictionary/json should be
Key:Value
Any help on this would be great.
Thank you.

Comment: Please read how to ask good question in help center for give best feedback for activities here : https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Have a look at `FOR JSON`. If you're stuck, then show us some sample data, expected results **and** what *you* have tried to solve the problem. What articles did you read? What about them didn't you understand? What SQL have you written so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried for json auto, I am getting the column name also in that case I am getting [{"Key" : columnvalueforKey, "Value": columnvalueforValue}] but I am expecting [{columnvalueforKey : columnvalueforValue}]

Comment: @Amirhossein thank you will definitely go through them.

Comment: Select StringKey,StringValue from Locale where Language ='en-us' for json auto I am trying this query

Comment: Sounds like you need to [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) your data before using [for json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server).

Comment: It is not possible to get dynamic keys with `FOR JSON` unless you use dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example data...

```sql
create table dbo.Example (
  ID int,
  [Key] varchar(10),
  Value varchar(10)
);
insert dbo.Example (ID, [Key], Value)
values
  (1, 'Foo', 'Bar'),
  (2, 'Baz', 'Chaz');
```

If you perform the following query on it:

```sql
select ID, [Key], Value
from dbo.Example
for json path;
```

You'll get the result where the object keys are the column names from the table:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Key": "Foo",
        "Value": "Bar"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Key": "Baz",
        "Value": "Chaz"
    }
]
```

It sounds like you're wanting to [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) those using a query like the following:

```sql
select ID, [Foo], [Baz]
from (
  select ID, [Key], Value
  from dbo.Example
) src
pivot (max(Value) for [Key] in ([Foo], [Baz])) p
for json path;
```

Which yields the following result instead:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Foo": "Bar"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Baz": "Chaz"
    }
]
```

The downside here is that you either (a) have to know all possible values of `Key` ahead of time so that they can be encoded in the statement, or (b) you have to write dynamic SQL statements that include the current set of values of `Key`.